# What of these two multithrading layouts is better?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a multithread layout where there is a manager object and a lot of workers objects.

I have doubt in which layout is better to use:

> 1 - The workers run in a loop and ask for a "new job" to the manager
>   constantly after finished.

or

> 2 - The manager give new jobs to the workers after they finish each
>   job.

Are there any recommendations for this?

Comment: The recommendation would be to use an executor service and let Java do the allocation of tasks to workers. :-)  Is your question which kind of service to use?

Comment: I prefer the second option. I don't know if its faster, but it is more flexible, easier to update, and easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question I have wrestled with many times. Each time I have chosen for the specific situation I am coding for. You should do the same.

However, to chose correctly you must study the two approaches carefully.

Consider a test case.

> You have thousands of files to process.

---

### 1. The workers are in control.

The `manager` becomes a queue of all of the files to process. You create a fixed number of `worker` threads which request the next file from the manager and repeat until the list is exhausted.

#### Consequences

You usually end up having to `synchronize` access to the queue.

You can tinker with the number of workers to attain maximal throughput for your hardware architecture.

Sometimes you can dynamically adjust the number of workers depending on the current load but this can be tricky. If successful you can often achieve an exceptionally optimal solution.

---

### 2. The manager is in control.

The `manager` creates a new `Callable` for every file and adds it to an `Executor` controlled thread pool.

#### Consequences

Well ... just about the same if you think about it. The only difference really is that the executor does the queueing.

There is less synchronization required (except of course internally in the `Executor`).

Dynamically adjusting the number of threads is not trivial but I expect one could subclass the `Executor` to achieve this.

---

**In summary**

The two architectures are very nearly the same. A number of threads process a sequence of items in parallel.

The differences are more in the dynamics and the footprint.

When the workers are in control, a known number of objects are present at any time. An extensive queue can build up but these would presumably be small objects. Work is done at a fixed and predicable pace. If the work starts to pile up you have to make a special effort to deal with it.

When the manager is in control there can be an explosion of workers, most of which are just sitting around waiting for the Executor. Essentially, the Executor becomes the manager and the Thread pool holds the workers.

I personally prefer the workers being in control. Mostly I suppose because given two essentially similar architectures I normally prefer the one with the most predictable footprint. I plan to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

They really aren't THAT different in principle. I think it really comes down to how you go about implementing the logic to do either of these things. I could see that making more of a difference than which you wind up going with.

The key two part 2 though, is that the manager would need to know if the worker has finished a job. So really at that point the workers still need to tell the manager, which is pretty much the same thing  as asking for a new job.

I think it really comes down to how you plan to do IPC. In theory I think the 2nd one is the better option, but it depends how elegantly you make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). The manager adds jobs to the queue in a loop, and the workers take jobs from the queue and do them in a loop.